# Does MySQL support user defined data types

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to define (alias) a base data type in MySQL?

Currently I would like to define UUID as char(32), and then use UUID as the type throughout the schema definition.  As we're prototyping at the moment, UUID is very likely to change - I'd like to ensure that this change is reflected consistently throughout the schema.

I'm thinking something like:

alias type UUID char(32);

Thanks in advance!

Comment: An uuid consists of 36 chars, if it contains dashes.

Answer (score 9):

In this case a text preprocesor like M4 or any C-language preprocesor may be useful.

If you have the following in file tables.sql:

```
define(UUID, char(32))
create table mytable1 (my_uuid UUID);
create table mytable2 (my_uuid UUID);
```

Running

```
$ m4 tables.sql
```

you'll get:

```
create table mytable1 (my_uuid char(32));
create table mytable2 (my_uuid char(32));
```

Comment: An uuid consists of 36 chars, if it contains dashes.

Answer (score -1):

well ENUM does the work until certain expectation of your custom data types, but i'm too hoping to look forward to this topic

Comment: Please be more specific and provide a clear explanation of your solution, preferably with examples.