# user defined sql datatypes in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know if its possible to create a user defined sql datatype. For example, a datatype can be 'fruit' and then the possiblities could be 'apple', 'pear', and 'orange'. Is this possible?

Comment: Already been asked and answered [here][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138392/does-mysql-support-user-defined-data-types

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by foampile, [the question has already been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138392/does-mysql-support-user-defined-data-types).

However, in your case, you could use the [ENUM type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/enum.html):

```
CREATE TABLE my_fruits (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    fruit ENUM('apple', 'pear', 'orange'),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);

INSERT INTO my_fruits(fruit) VALUES('pear'), ('apple'), ('orange'), ('pear');
```

[SQLfiddle to show usage](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00c3a/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [enum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) for such cases.

For example

```
create table testing_fruits
(fruits enum('apple', 'grapes', 'banana',...));
```

But problem in this approach is that you will have to use enum again and again...

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I don't need to create a new datatype. What I really need to do is create a new 'fruits' table, make a foreign key 'fruit_type' column in my 'meal' table, and make 'apple', 'pear', and 'orange' rows inside the fruits table. Now, you can only insert a fruit into the 'meal' table if it exists in the 'fruits' table.

Comment: This solution is probably more flexible, no need to change the table schema to allow new fruits to be added into the table.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) your own answer, if this is what you prefer.